# if Q>1.5, then s1=a and s2= b, otherwise, compute C=some formula and then s1=min(a,c) and s2=min(a Q, C)

Tags: excel, if-statement, reference, cell

I need to write in excel the following statements.

**if Q>1.5, then s1=a and s2= b, 
otherwise, compute C=some formula and then s1=min(a,C) and s2=min(a+Q, C)**

I am not being able to give a reference in the if statement for both s1 and s2. and i am not being able to write properly the if_false_statement 
help please.

Comment: "I am not being able to give a reference in the if statement for both s1 and s2." Because that is **not** how an `IF` formula works in Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to calculate s1 and s2 using separate formulas for each. Using your algebraic expression, this means that the cells holding the values for s1 and s2 would need to have the following formulas, respectively.

```
  s1:  =if(Q>1.5,a,min(a,C))
  s2:  =if(Q>1.5,b,min(a+Q,C)
```

In the worksheet, this might be translated as follows (for sake of example, I've assumed that the computation C is simply 'a + b').

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!!! worked perfectly!!